# AngularJs + Bootstrap - Simple toggle button with MY images?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a simple toggle button that has a specific image of my choice when it is pressed, hovered and un-pressed (regular mode). simple as that.
I couldn't find how...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple directive, it might help you get a feeling

http://jsfiddle.net/0eon0xcc/

```
controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.clicked = false;
    $scope.entered = false;
    $scope.imageUrl = $scope.defaultImg;

    $scope.click = function() {
        $scope.entered = false;
        $scope.clicked = !$scope.clicked;
        checkStates();
    }

    $scope.hover = function(val) {
      $scope.entered = val;
        checkStates();
    }

    function checkStates() {
        if ($scope.entered) {
            $scope.imageUrl = $scope.hoveredImg;
        } else {
            if ($scope.clicked) {
                $scope.imageUrl = $scope.pressedImg;
            } else {
                $scope.imageUrl = $scope.defaultImg;
            }            
        }
    }
```